# get_template_part for specific page

Tags: php, theme-development, get-template-part

I have tried adding a file inside my `header.php`, but it will not load correctly. I get this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
>   get_tempalte_part()

Here is my markup in my `header.php`:

```
<html class="m-0">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <title>*TITLE*</title>
        <?php wp_head(); ?>
    </head>

    <body <?php body_class(); ?> >

            <section id="header" class="container-fluid no-gutters">

                <?php
                if( is_page( 'blog' ) ) {
                    get_template_part( 'inc/fd-', 'blog' );
                } else {
                    get_tempalte_part( 'inc/fd-', 'default' );
                }
                ?>

                <?php if( is_search() ) {
                    fd_title_search();
                } else if( is_product() || is_account_page() || is_page( 'contact-us' ) || is_page( 'shipping' ) || is_page( 'privacy' ) || is_page( 'terms' ) || is_page( 'faq' ) || is_page( 'about-us' ) || is_page( 'home' ) ) {
                    echo '';
                } else if( is_product_category() ) {
                    fd_title_product_category();
                } else if( is_shop() ) {
                    fd_title_shop();
                } else if( is_page( 'wishlist' ) ) {
                    fd_title_wishlist();
                } else {
                    fd_title_default();
                } ?>

            </section>
```

I am trying to load `fd-blog.php` if it is the 'Blog' page, otherwise load the `fd-default.php`, but I keep getting an error, no matter what I try! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, but there's no need for the dash (`-`). Just `inc/fd` as in `get_template_part( 'inc/fd', 'blog' );`

Comment: And there's a typo: `get_tempalte_part` - that should be `get_template_part` - in `get_tempalte_part( 'inc/fd-', 'default' );`

Comment: @SallyCJ, It actually helped solve my problem! One was the typo (how embarrassing) and the other was the unnecessary trailing dash! All working! Please submit it as an answer so I can mark it accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a supplement to the other answer.

> I am trying to load `fd-blog.php` if it is the 'Blog' page, otherwise
>   load the `fd-default.php`

To actually load the template file, you should remove the dash (`-`):

```php
get_template_part( 'inc/fd', 'blog' );    // loads inc/fd-blog.php
get_template_part( 'inc/fd', 'default' ); // loads inc/fd-default.php
```

So just `inc/fd`, and here's the relevant code in [get_template_part](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/):

```php
// Example when you call get_template_part( 'inc/fd', 'blog' ), $name below is 'blog'.
if ( '' !== $name ) {
    $templates[] = "{$slug}-{$name}.php";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've spelt it wrong: `get_tempalte_part`, "tempalte", needs to be `get_template_part()`.

Comment: Well, that's embarrassing...lol